# Memory Consumption of Collection Types

Tags: vb.net, memory, collections

I am trying to make a small app that uses a multiple hierarchy of type List within a List for some 20-30 levels. I tried with:

`System.Collections.ComponentModel.ObservableCollection`, but at run time, I got an `OutOfMemoryException` error. Then, I tried with List, and this time I did not get such an error.

What type of collection consumes the least amount of space? Or, what would be a good way to achieve this type of hierarchy? I just need a collection; I don't need change notifications, etc. I am using .NET 4 with VB, Linq, and WPF. I achieved the code looping process with `Parallel.ForEach` threading.

Edit:
The Program is for string the file system data into Sql CE DB and retrieving it back.  Hence, the hierarchy can be of 20-30 levels also.

Edit: There would be about 80000 Queries with linq for getting the hierarchy. The Type of data I am using is as follows:

```
Public Structure FileRecord
        Property ID As String
        Property Namee As String
        Property Size As String
        Property IsFolder As Boolean
        Property DateModified As Date
        Property FullPath As String
        Property Disk As String
        Property ParentID As String
        Property Items As List(Of FileRecord)
End Structure
```

Comment: I think if you explained a little more about the "hierarchy" you're dealing with it might help. Neither ObservableCollection<T> nor List<T> are designed to deal with hierarchical data.

Comment: If you don't need change notification, don't use ObservableCollection<T>, since change notification is the primary reason for its existence.

Comment: @Wayne , I edited the question with some more info  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance characteristics of the various .NET collection classes vary widely, and the type of collection you'll want to use will also depend on how you will want to access the collection. As usual, there are trade-offs to be made between performance (in time and memory) and simplicity or convenience.

That said, one of the simplest and most performant collection types in .NET is probably [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx).

Comment: The data type is a structure and I added its details to the question.  When it comes to performance, what collection type can I use mainly for the speed of querying?

Comment: A hashset would give you the fastest read time, but you'll have overhead with writing to it.

Comment: With the help from your information, I tested with few collections types like: System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag(Of ); System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue(Of ); HashSet(of T); List(of T);    out of all these, the ConcurrentQueue works the fastest at least for multithread applications.  Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2):

The overhead associated with each collection wouldn't cause an OOM exception, as described above because both implement `List<T>`.  The ObservableCollection can be used in conjunction with INotifyCollectionChanged to alert views and presenters/viewmodels of changes to the collection.

The bigger question is, what kind of type are you using?  If you're running out of memory, each type might be allocating an unnecessary amount of memory.  Also, I wouldn't use an ObservableCollection unless you intend to use binding.

Comment: edited the question, the data type is a structure and I added it to question.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, after some digging into the issue came to know that the OOM exceptions is result of List Type not being able to keep with Parallel Threading speed, it could not update its src and other indexes.   Thank you for the support.